# Core Data sum of entity attributes between two date

Tags: ios, ios5, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have an entity that has an amount attribute [NSNumber double] ... a NSDate attribute and 2 boolean attributes (stored as NSNumber) ... Is there a way to obtain the sum of the "amount" attribute such that the date attribute is between 2 given dates, and one of the Boolean attributes is set to YES... I'm guessing it can be done without fetching all entities and adding them in a for each ...

```
 // sum of expenses this month
NSFetchRequest *fetchMonthExp = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entityExp = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:kTransaction inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
[fetchMonthExp setEntity:entityExp];
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                          initWithKey:kDate ascending:NO];
[fetchMonthExp setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

NSPredicate *predFetchEx = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(isExpense = YES) AND (date > %@) AND (date < %@) AND (isPendingScheduledTransaction = NO) AND (isDebtRepaiment = NO) AND (isLoanRepaiment = NO) AND (isDebt = NO) AND (isLoan = NO)",[self beginingOfMonthForDate:[NSDate date]],[NSDate date]];
[fetchMonthExp setPredicate:predFetchEx];

NSExpression *ex = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"sum:" 
                                             arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"totalAmountInDefaultCurrency"]]];

NSExpressionDescription *ed = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
[ed setName:@"resultExpSum"];
[ed setExpression:ex];
[ed setExpressionResultType:NSDoubleAttributeType];

NSArray *properties = [NSArray arrayWithObject:ed];
[fetchMonthExp setPropertiesToFetch:properties];

NSError *error1 = nil;
NSArray *resultsEx = [self.context executeFetchRequest:fetchMonthExp error:&error1]; <- EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code = 2, address = 0x0)
if(resultsEx == nil) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to fetch exp sum: %@", [error1 localizedDescription]);
    NSArray* detailedErrors = [[error1 userInfo] objectForKey:NSDetailedErrorsKey];
    if(detailedErrors != nil && [detailedErrors count] > 0) {
        for(NSError* detailedError in detailedErrors) {
            NSLog(@"  DetailedError: %@", [detailedError userInfo]);
        }
    }
}
```

What is with that error ....

```
-[UIView count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7856150
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to look into `NSExpression` and `NSPredicate`.  [Here](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/11/nsexpression.html) is a dated, but useful, link which has some information to get you started.